# How to create the below htm code dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need the below code to be generated dynamically

```
<div class="app" style="display:none">
    <input id="application" type="radio" name="choice" value="Albert">
    <label>Albert</label>
    <input id="application" type="radio" name="choice" value="Huston">
    <label>Huston</label>
</div>
<div class="marks" style="display:none">
    <input id="subject" type="radio" name="choice" value="ten">
    <label>10</label>
    <input id="subject" type="radio" name="choice" value="twelve">
    <label>12</label>
</div>
```

The class, id, value and the string between the label are to be dynamically added. I will be getting these values from a for loop, which I am iterating over the rows in a table. Please help.

Comment: A loop where? server side, client side? Do you access a DB table or an html table? what have you tried so far? Is HTML code being added or is it just read from somewhere on page load?

Comment: what does your data look like? object or array? what loop have you tried so far

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/append

Comment: Sorry.. The loop is in Javascript. I have read the values from a table in database, and created a table in frontend.

Comment: Can you guide me on how to create the above code in question using jquery, assuming the value, id, class and label are as in question?

Comment: You have to read the docs for jquery, here nobody codes for you, try something and then show us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```js
   var first={
        class:'app',
        id:'application',
        values:[['Albert', 'Albert'],['Huston', 'Huston']]
   };

   var second={
        class:'marks',
        id:'subject',
        values:[['ten', 10],['twelve', 12]]
   };

  function add_dynamic_al(_obj){
     var div=$('<div/>');
     div.addClass(_obj.class);
     //div.hide();  //if need  display:none

     var lbl1=$('<label/>');

     var inp1=$('<input/>');
     inp1.attr({'id':_obj.id, 'type':'radio', name:'choice',}).val(_obj.values[0][0]);

     lbl1.append(inp1).append(_obj.values[0][1]);  //for structure '<label><input />name</label>'

     div.append(lbl1);

     var lbl2=$('<label/>');

     var inp2=$('<input/>');
     inp2.attr({'id':_obj.id, 'type':'radio', name:'choice',}).val(_obj.values[1][0]);

     lbl2.append(inp2).append(_obj.values[1][1]);

     div.append(lbl2);

     $('body').append(div);

  }
```

```css
       div{
         display:inline-block;
         border-style:solid;
         border-width:2px;
         border-color:gray;
         padding:10px;
       }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


   <input type="button" value="add first element" onclick="add_dynamic_al(first);" />
   <input type="button" value="add second element" onclick="add_dynamic_al(second);" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: How can I achieve the same thing by having an object array(array containing first and second) and iterating over them? I need to create all the radio buttons(4 in this case) on a single button click.

Comment: I added a variant with processing an array of objects

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you need:

```js
    var my_obj=[{
        class:'app',
        id:'application',
        values:[['Albert', 'Albert'],['Huston', 'Huston']]
     },{
        class:'marks',
        id:'subject',
        values:[['ten', 10],['twelve', 12]]
     }];





  function create_dynamic_el_from_obj_arr(_obj_arr){
      for(var key in _obj_arr){
             var cur_el=_obj_arr[key];
              var div=$('<div/>');
             div.addClass(cur_el.class);
             //div.hide();  //if need  display:none
             var cur_el_values=_obj_arr[key].values;
             for(var kv in cur_el_values){
                 var lbl=$('<label/>');
                 var inp=$('<input/>');
                 inp.attr({'id':cur_el.id, 'type':'radio', name:'choice',}).val(cur_el_values[kv][0]);
                 lbl.append(inp).append(cur_el_values[kv][1]);
                 div.append(lbl);
             }
             $('body').append(div);

      }
  }
```

```css
       div{
         display:inline-block;
         border-style:solid;
         border-width:2px;
         border-color:gray;
         padding:10px;
       }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


      <input type="button" value="add all element" onclick="create_dynamic_el_from_obj_arr(my_obj);" /><br/>
```